# Android How To Properly Notify Data Set Changed for ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to update my list and display the updated list in my activity. Every time I do so I get the following error

```
 The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.
 Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread,
 but only from the UI thread.
```

Here is my code, I am using an AsyncTask to achieve this task. I call notifyDataSetChanged() on my adapter but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
  class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {
        GregorianCalendar currentDateclone = (GregorianCalendar) currentDate.clone();
        ListPopulater2.listPopulate(currentDateclone, 7, items, Id);
                    //method to update list info




    }

    // -- gets called just before thread begins
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(SectionListExampleActivity.this, "", "Loading..."); //display progress bar
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    // -- called as soon as doInBackground method completes
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d("postExecute", "here");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        progressdialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but why are you using `runOnUiThread(...)` in `onPostExecute(...)`? All methods of `AsyncTask` (except `doInBackground(...)`) run on the UI thread anyway.

Comment: Something I was just trying out, works the same without it. I just removed it for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving:

```
ListPopulater2.listPopulate(currentDateclone, 7, items, Id);
```

to your `onPostExecute`.

The reason that this worked is because you need to update the list after you've completed all your background activity, not while you are doing it. You can use the `onProgressUpdate`, but that is for your progress dialog. Updating you list view should be done after you have all you data, otherwise, you will get the error you did because the UI runs on the main thread, and you are trying to update it with the background thread.

As for the progress dialog, there is a purpose. If you are doing something that is going to take awhile to complete, the dialog will tell the user how close you are to completing the background task.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That worked, but any explanation why that would be? Also this kind of kills the purpose of having a progressdialog

Comment: I kind of understand what you are saying, but if I move the populate method to onPostExecute then nothing is being done in the doInBackground method. My understanding with the AsyncTask was that loading can be done in the background and then once completed onPostExecute is called.

Comment: I think in method listPopulate you were trying to update some data models which were not getting reflected in onPostExecute may be because doInBackground runs in background thread?

Comment: Right. In the `doInBackground` you are running on a separate thread. This is for things like pulling data from web services, parsing data, etc. When you want to update your list, you have to do that on the main thread, as a list is for the user and the main thread is the UI thread. You can't update the adapter unless you do it on the main thread. In your method, you are cloning data on the background thread, then update it once it is done.

Comment: I see, my populate method is doing exactly this. It is pulling data from the web and just updating the information, it does not actually update the list. Is it because I am updating information the adapter relies on?

Comment: Yes. The adapter is a buffer between your UI and processes. Your populate method is taking all the data you have collected/manipulated and then sends it to the adapter, which then transforms it into a list view.

Answer (score 2):

When Ever you want to do something which deal with the UI you have to do that task in UI thread.
So for this you can use 2 approach:

1. use runOnUi() method
2. Use OnPostExecute() method

And you have to use notifyDatasetchanged() at that place where you are setting adapter in listView.